Show that polynomials with a given factor form a subspace
I have a question for one of my assignments but I don't understand how to solve it.

Let $P_n$ be the set of real polynomials of degree at most $n$, show
that
$S=\{p ∈ P_7:x^2+x+4 $ is a factor of $p(x)\}$ is a subspace of  $P_7$

I know that to prove it is a subspace I need to show that it contains the zero vector, is closed under vector addition, and is closed under scalar multiplication. I know that it satisfies all those conditions because they are given, but I'm now sure how to prove it because I'm only given the factor.
A concern I have with the solution posted on a previous post with a similar question was to introduce a function $f$ such that $p=q*f$ where $q$ is the given factor. If $f$ has a non-zero coefficient for the $x^0$ factor, then that would mean it wouldn't include the zero vector
Edit: It is not given that the conditions are satisfied, but I am able to check if they are and I'm using the that function so see if it is. I am supposed to prove that satisfies those conditions without the knowing that it is.

Write out what it means for $f$ to have that as a factor.  Now prove that $f+g$ does that if both $f$ and $g$ do.

@Randall are you referring to $p$ when you say $f$? I'm confused what you mean by proving $f +g$

He means: Let $f,g \in S$.  Show $f+g \in S$.  This shows $S$ is closed under (vector) addition...

It's not hard (once you see it) to show $\vec{0} \in S$.  How did you convince yourself of this fact?

@EricTowers we are given a way to check if our conclusion is right, and it was simply a yes or no that it satisfies each condition, so we could check if it did.

Responding to recent addition:  If $p \in S$, then $p \in P_7$ and $(x^2 + x +4)|p$.  The latter means that there is a polynomial, $q(x)$, such that $p(x) = q(x) \cdot (x^2 + x + 4)$ and with the former, $q(x) \cdot (x^2 + x + 4)$ has degree at most $7$.

@EricTowers I understood that part, so that would mean $q(x)$ would have to be of degree 5. if $q(x)$ doesn't didn't contain the zero vector and was something like $x^5+3$, that would cause $p(x)$ to not contain the zero vector right?
Or are we assuming in this case that $f$ will satisfy this condition?

Think of it this way:  $S = { p(x) \in P_7 \mid \exists q(x) \in P_7 \text { such that } p(x)=(x^2+x+4)q(x) }$.  Now can you see why $S$ satisfies all of the axioms?

@RobertShore I can see how it satisfies the vector addition and scalar multiplication, but I still don't see how it satisfies the zero vector. Even if $q(x)$ is a subset of $P_7$, it can still only have the highest degree of 5. And the logic in my head for previous response is still stands, unless my understanding is flawed there.

"that would mean $q(x)$ would have to be of degree $5$".  No.  That would mean that $q(x)$ is of degree at most $5$.

It would be really weird if the zero vector of the subspace were different from the zero vector of the whole space.  The zero vector of $P_7$ is the polynomial $0$.  If $0 = p(x) = (x^2+x+4)q(x)$ and $q(x)$ has degree at most $5$, what must $q(x)$ be?

@EricTowers well in this case $q(x)$ would have to be 0, but $q(x)$ could also be $x^2$ and if we have the vector $<0,0,0,0,0,0,0>$ it would still satisfy the zero vector condition.

If a subset of a vector space is non-empty and closed under linear combinations (or sums and scalar multiplications) then it automatically contains the zero vector.

You seem to be confused. There are no conditions on the other factor $f$. It can be the zero polynomial, but it doesn't have to.

@JyrkiLahtonen for your first reply, are you saying that as long as it satisfies two of the conditions the third one is automatically satisfied?

@JyrkiLahtonen I think it's the fact that there's no conditions for $f$ that's confusing me. Am I to assume that $f$ satisfies the condition by using it?

Is this supposed to be a trivial conclusion?

Are you clear as to why
$$S={ f(x)(x^2+x+4)\mid \text{$f$ any polynomial, $f(x)(x^2+x+4)\in P_7$}}?$$
In other words, do you understand basic set description lingo? Above $f(x)$ can be any polynomial as long as $f(x)(x^2+x+4)\in P_7$.

@JyrkiLahtonen Yes, I understand the set description above. But I still don't get how it proves the existence of the zero vector

$f(x)=0$ is a polynomial, and $0(x^2+x+4)=0$ is the zero vector of $P_7$.

To say that $x^2+x+4$ is a factor of the polynomial $p(x)$ simply means that $p(x)$ is expressible as
$$
p(x)=(x^2+x+4)q(x)
$$
for some other polynomial $q(x)$.  This is exactly akin to saying $5$ is a factor of $40$ because $40 = 5 \times 8$.
So, there is a straightforward "rule of membership" for your set $S$:  the polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $7$ or less belongs to $S$ is and only if $p(x)=(x^2+x+4)q(x)$ for some other polynomial $q(x)$.  [Don't worry about the degree of $q$ right now.]
Now we can easily check the subspace conditions.  First, note that $p(x)=0$ meets the "rule of membership" for $S$:  $0 = (x^2+x+4)\cdot 0$ [so just take $q(x)=0$, a valid choice].  Thus $0 \in S$.
Now suppose $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ meet the "rule of membership" for $S$:  they are each degree $7$ or less, and $f(x)=(x^2+x+4)q(x)$ and $g(x) = (x^2+x+4)r(x)$ for some mystery polynomials $q(x)$ and $r(x)$.  Clearly, $f(x)+g(x)$ still has degree $7$ or less.  Moreover,
$$
f(x)+g(x) = (x^2+x+4)q(x) + (x^2+x+4)r(x) = (x^2+x+4)(q(x)+r(x)).
$$
As $q(x)+r(x)$ is still a polynomial, we've shown that $f(x)+g(x)$ meets the "rule of membership" for $S$.  Hence $f(x)+g(x) \in S$ so $S$ is closed under addition.
You can now prove closure under scalar multiplication using the exact same strategy:  just check the rule of membership for $cf(x)$ if $f(x) \in S$ and $c$ is a constant.
